Understandig the Chiddushei HaRim on the sin of Nadav and Avihu
The Chiddushei HaRim (Parshas Shemini, p. 168) explains what really lies behind the sin of Nadav and Avihu. He seems to explain that when G-d gives us a mitzvah, doing that mitzvah, without knowing the motive for it, the mitzvah he performs, ultimately elevates him in his holiness. Since Nadav and Avihu did not get commanded to bring the ketores the way they did, they sinned.

ונתגלה אור המצוה והעבודה האמיתית. והנס הזה הי' לפנחס מכח נשמתם שנתעברה בו שהי' התבערה הזאת שלא השגיח על הציווי ע"י הלכה הבועל ארמית קנאים וכו' ואין מורים כן, כי העיקר שיעשה הכל רק מצד עצם הקנאה ולא מצד הציווי של הקב"ה והחטא של נדב ואביהוא הי' ממש חטא זה שעשו שלא בגלל הציווי רק משום שבער בם אש ה' ע"כ הי' תקונם ג"כ במעשה הזה שעיקר הדין והמצוה שלא מחמת צווי כלל כי אין מורים כן


נדב ואביהוא היו בל"ס אנשים גדולים ועשו הכל לשם שמים, אבל הי' חסר להם הציווי, הצו של הקב"ה צריך להיות כח המניע האיתן ביותר העולה על כל שכל שהוא, ק"ו אם אדם עושה מצוה בגלל הציווי הגם שאין לו כל מושג על גדלות המצוה וטעמה וערכה, נותן לו הציווי כוח וחיות לרוממו לקדושה עצומה, ובשביל זה אומרים אשר קדשנו במצוותיו וצונו, הציונו הוא עיקר הכח המקדש את האדם

The Chiddushei HaRim says that:

The sin of Nadav and Avihu was exactly this sin— they acted not because of the command, but because the fire of G-d burned within them.

He continues (loose translation):

Nadav and Avihu were indeed great men and did everything for the sake of Heaven, but they lacked the command, the command of the Holy One, blessed be He, needs to be the most potent motivating force that surpasses all reason. How much more so if a person performs a commandment because of the command, even though he has no concept of the greatness and the reason and the value of the commandment, the command gives him strength and vitality to elevate him to immense holiness. For this reason, we say 'Who has sanctified us with His commandments and commanded us,' for the command is the essence of the power that sanctifies a person."

But why is this considered a sin?
Can someone please explain what the Chiddushei HaRim says and how to resolve the seemingly contradiction that G-d did instruct "the sons of Aharon to put fire upon the altar, and lay the wood in order upon the fire".

Isn't that what the passuk itself says was their sin? The Chiddushei Harim is giving a deeper explanation of that.

I have trouble understanding what the chiddushei harim says and what it means, not what the sin was according to the peshat-level of the posuk.

He's saying the main reason a person should do a mitzvah is to fulfill Hashem's commandment. So it's the same as the passuk. It's also what Chazal say about גדול המצווה ועושה ממי שאינו מצווה ועושה.

You may find it helpful to investigate the subjects of Iyov, Eliyahu (meaning Pinchas) and the concept of Yibum as they relate to Nadav and Avihu. They all derive from aspects of Adam HaRishon. In particular Sefer Kehillat Yaacov from Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles discusses this subject.

@YaacovDeane thank you for helping me out. Would you be able/willing to (begin writing) write an answer explaining what the Kehillas Yaakov says?

I don't have the time right now and the sefer isn't at hand either. But if I get a chance to review it again, bli neder, perhaps later. If you don't have the sefer yourself, you should go look at it on Hebrewbooks.org. It's alphabetical, so the subjects are easy to find. The work is actually looking at the sources that he cites. Definitely worth it, if you haven't looked into it before.

@YaacovDeane that would be wonderful, since I did not find any (on Otzar I found only a gematria-related teaching but not what you said).

https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44143&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=

@YaacovDeane TY, but as I mentioned. I was not able to locate the page(s). I have trouble reading Rashi-script, so searching for me isn't a option. You have a lot of knowledge, so your help would be much appreciated if you have the time.

@Shmuel What do you believe the sin was according to the peshat-level of the pasuk?

@joelk getting too close to G-d, getting into an area they weren’t allowed in etc..

@Shmuel. OK. Just note the end of Vayikra 10:1 - אש זרה אשר לא צוה אתם. So your question from Vayikra 1:7 is not really on the Chiddushei HaRim's approach, but on how to understand Vayikra 10:1.

@JoelK You have a point, but...... The Chiddushei HaRim, as I interpret him, says that since they weren't commanded, doing what they weren't commanded to do, was considered sinning. But to that, the posuk in Vayikra 1:7 clearly says they were commanded.
